# "No module named cloud" while deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pypi

I have built an app for Google App Engine and while I tried running the app, it worked well. But when I deployed it, it threw internal server 500 error. When I checked the error report, it said, "No module named cloud in the directory"

Below is my requirements.txt

```
gunicorn==19.3.0
twilio==6.8.4
google-cloud-automl==0.1.1
google-cloud-storage==1.0.0
google-cloud==0.34.0
GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient==1.9.22.1
```

My Yaml file is as follows

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
handlers:
- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Imports used in the python file are

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl
from google.cloud import storage
```

It worked when I ran manually. But after deploying , the error is

```
ImportError: No module named cloud
<module> (/base/data/home/apps/..
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to deploy to the "First Generation" App Engine runtime. Unfortunately, you can't use the `google-cloud` Python libraries there.

The good news is that you can use the "Second Generation" instead, which allows you to install any library, including any of the `google-cloud` libraries like `google-cloud-storage`.

See this link for the difference between the two generations: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation

Google App Engine Python 3 Standard Environment Documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/

Comment: So you meant to say that, only the yaml file needs to be changed that reflects second generation so that it can be deployed ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [the `google-cloud` package has been deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/%20%22the%20%60google-cloud%60%22%20package%20has%20been%20deprecated).

Second, you can't use the `google-cloud-*` libraries in App Engine Standard. You have to use other alternatives, like `GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient`.

Comment: Since I am using AutoML stuffs, I think app engine doesnt have its standalone package for AutoML. Moreover GoogleAppEngineCloudStorage is also in my requirements.txt as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute `pip install google-cloud-automl`.

This will fix the problem.